# HTML Website too wide

Tags: css, html

This is the website I am modifying: sb460training.org

Here is the code snippet:

```
#apdiv1 {
position: absolute;
width: 2815px;
height: 276px;
z-index: 1;
top: 1px;
left: 0px;
background-color: #000;
}
#apdiv2 {
position: absolute;
width: 3150px;
height: 115px;
z-index: 2;
left: 0px;
top: 230px;
}
#apdiv3 {
position: absolute;
width: 221px;
height: 411px;
z-index: 3;
left: 0px;
top: 259px;
background-color: #FFF;
}
#apdiv4{
position: absolute;
width: 2853px;
height: 115px;
z-index: 4;
left: 219px;
top: 401px;
}
```

Do you know what the width dimensions should be so I can get rid of the annoyingly extra space that shows up to the right of the web page?
Thanks

Comment: The problem is that everything has `position:absolute;`. This means that everything is positioned relative to the upper left hand corner of the page. One way you could eliminate this is to set a width and center the main div using something like `margin:0 auto;`. If you want to maintain the positioning of the child elements, just set the main div to have `position:relative` and the child elements will be absolutely positioned not to the page origin, but to the main div.

Comment: the width in css apdiv1,apdiv2,apdiv4 are quite high

Comment: I will also agree with @PravinS that the widths are very high, but even decreasing them won't be consistent among devices. Smaller resolution screens may still have to scroll horizontally.

Comment: "what the width dimensions **should** be" is kind of an odd question. They _should be_ whatever the owner of the website wants them to be. Is the website being viewed on Phones? Tablets? Desktop computers? Custom touch screens? TV sets? Should it be viewable on all of those devices? All of the Divs on that page have a different width. You should create a single div to contain them them all, and set your maximum width on that (assuming you're not considering responsive design), and then adapt your design around that.

Comment: Well, I really just want the extra space to the right to be chopped off entirely and would like the page to end nearby the circular purple image that I use as a site map. I'll try adding the margins, and changing the container widths to 100%, and see what happens from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the other answers, I agree that your CSS should change the fixed widths to 100%.

However, in your HTML you have img elements with explicit widths, to substitute background colours. For example, in the "apDiv2" DIV element, you have an in-line image containing white, "SB460_Pic/Secondary title2.jpg". This image is set to 2128px wide, causing the page to extend horizontally.

I would recommend removing the images that are being used to pad the right of each DIV, and instead set background colours in CSS.

**UPDATE**

Quick and dirty example:

http://pastebin.com/4PmZN1r4

Comment: oh, okay. Yeah, I was thinking about removing the .jpg file myself b/c the apDiv2 is really the only bothersome part of the index.html file after the width of everything else gets fixed to 100%. The example you provided certainly helps me fix that horizontal extension issue tremendously. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped; if you've got the time, I'd also recommend changing the text that's currently an image file into actual text. It'll search better and make life much easier for coding. Don't forget to up-vote or select answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. change all your container widths to 100%.
2. give your html a width:100%; margin:0;
3. give your body a fixed width:1200px or so.
4. set your body with a margin: 0 auto if you want it centered.

Comment: I'll get back to you about this, b/c I'm currently debugging another issue on a different project at work as well.

Comment: Sure.  You'll still have issues with width from other absolute elements that are too wide,  but let's get closer to the width you need a step at a time. This site is a mess brotha

Comment: Yeah, I know it is. So I added the margin: 0; and width: 100%; for the first 2 apdiv's. And you can take a look at the site now and see what it gives me. It works alignment wise for the 1st apdiv, but the 2nd one chops off sooner than I would like. I think I may have to resize the .jpg header file used for the "Helping teachers recognize symptoms..." sentence. I originally didn't make the site. It was a project just given to me from the previous developer that worked here. Simple website I know. But the guy who made it certainly made the format of it terribly messy.

Comment: Same result happens with:
margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

I've heard the same similar issue.
all you need to do is try working with margin set to 0 and auto.

in most cases, try eliminating the use of 'position absolute' and work more with margin, padding and position relative.